# Asynchronous socket, receive string messages

Tags: c#, multithreading, string, sockets, console

Good evening, sorry in advance for writing so much but I don't know where the error is...

My client application is receiving from the server asynchronously. I want to transfer a bunch of stuff at once (the contents of an array, a couple of hundred bytes).

I want the server to be able to send "commands", and have a function on the client side act according to these commands, for example if the message from the server reads `"print_hello"`, it should call a function that prints hello.

Now, it's my understanding that when receiving data asynchronously, I can't know how much of the data has been sent (or if more data than I expected has been sent), so I need to store all the data in a buffer, and when an "end of command" (for example, `'!'`) sign has been received, it should know to call the function.

So far this makes sense to me, but I'm having trouble implementing it. In my DataReceived callback function, I have this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Raw data: {0}", data));
mainBuffer += data;
Console.WriteLine(mainBuffer);
```

mainBuffer is declared as `volatile static string mainBuffer = "";`
The first line prints correctly, and goes through all of the data as expected. However, when I print out the `mainBuffer`, it only prints out the very first set of data I receieved, the rest does not get added to the buffer.

What could cause this? Thread safety issues? Am I not reading the latest value of mainBuffer? I can't use breakpoints to debug this.

Sample output:

```
Raw data: ABC
ABC
Raw data: DEF
ABC
RAW data: GHI
ABC
```

Small update, I tried using a `volatile static int` as well, and it increments and prints correctly after each `DataReceived()`. The string still does not get updated however.

Comment: Where did you declare mainBuffer? Are you sure you are not resetting it to "" every time you receive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your problem *"with the messing code lines!"*:

```
//of course the problem has noting to do with the string being volatile...
private volatile string mainBuffer = string.Empty;

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

while (networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
{
    string data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    Console.WriteLine("Raw data: {0}", data));
    mainBuffer += data;
    Console.WriteLine(mainBuffer);
}
```

Naturally the output of this code will be as you mentioned previously. Here is what is happening:

The `string` class in C# is an array of `char` start by pointer to the first `char` in the array and ends by the special "terminal" char `\0`.

When you create a byte array of `n` index, it will fill all indexes of the array with the default value of `byte` which is `0`. but `0` is just equals the terminal char `\0`

```
byte b = (byte)`\0`;\\the value of b will be 0
```

So, When you call `Read(buffer)`, the method will not *trim* the buffer to just *fit* the data read. so if the buffer size "here 1024" is larger than the data read, all the remaining bytes of the buffer will be equals to the terminal char '\0', So the array of chars of the generated string will be `ABC\0\0\0\0... to the index 1024`. When you add a string `DEF` to that it will add it at the last index of the `char` array "after last `\0`", the `char` array then will be `ABC\0\0\0\0...DEF`, but because of `DEF` is added after the terminal char(s) so the `Console.Write` will ignore all after the first `\0`!.

Also note while you debugging, if you point your mouse to the `mainBuffer` variable, you will see the actual data it contains maybe something like `ABC\0\0\0\0..DEF\0\0\0\0..GHI`

However to fix the problem and only generate a reliable string, Get the actual bytes read and generate the string only from it. So:

```
int dataRead = 0;

while ((dataRead = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    List<byte> actualBuffer = (new List<byte>(buffer)).GetRange(0, dataRead);

    string data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(actualBuffer.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("Raw data: {0}", data));
    mainBuffer += data;
    Console.WriteLine(mainBuffer);
}
```

It is wroth to mention here that you should consider using [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) instead of `string`.